# error: "Unauthenticated." Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

So I'm trying to store the id of my user in user_id but laravel gives the error:

{error: "Unauthenticated."}

while my user is logged in in my backoffice.

this is my routesApi.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Api',
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
    'middleware' => 'web'
], function () {
    $options = [
        'except' => [
            'create',
            'edit',
        ]
    ];

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN ');


    Route::middleware('auth')->post('optionelections', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

and this is the function for my store in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $optionElection = new OptionElection();
        $optionElection->user_id = Auth::id();
        $optionElection->option = Auth::name();
        $optionElection->votes = 0;
        $optionElection->election_id = $request['election_id'];
        $optionElection->accepted = 0;

        if ($optionElection->save()) {


            return response()
                ->json($optionElection);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `web` middleware group implements the `VerifyCSRFToken` middleware. This requires that every request to every route inside of this middleware group passes a `token`.

You're lacking a token in your request.

If this is a standard HTML form, then just add the following in it:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

If this is an ajax request, you can utilize the following:

```
token: window.Laravel.csrfToken
```

If that is not set, then add this to the head of your layout template:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {
        csrfToken: '{{csrf_token()}}'
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured that you forgot to exclude the URI From CSRF protection.

This should save your day:

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```